# Unsupported Delegation without primary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-delegate

I ran into an issue with kotlin delegation where I want to delegate the interface implementation to a variable. The problem is that the superclass has some other constructors that I would not want to lose really

```kotlin
interface Delegate
class CustomView(myRequiredDelegate: Delegate,context:Context): ViewGroup(context), Delegate by myRequiredDelegate
```

Now as you can see I will have problems with the android studio preview as there is no constructor(context: Context)
And also other problems with initializing from xml as I will have to create

```kotlin
class View(myRequiredDelegate: Delegate,context: Context): ViewGroup(context), Delegate by myRequiredDelegate{
   // as you can see here I can no longer have access to call super(context, attrs...)
   // which provide more attrs for the custom view
   // and not sure if kotlin provides any other way to access the other super constructors
   constructor(context: Context):this(dummyForDelegate,context)
}
```

I just want to know if there is a way to provide the delegation as so without breaking the super call chain not specifically for android but for any other case that might have the same delegation constraints...

Comment: This looks to me like the best way to do it. If the interface is needed to be able to display the preview, you would need that dummy implementation anyway.

Comment: When delegating you don't implement the interface the delegate is supposed to handle that...